# How to keep multiple instances of react-native-webview open (and mounted) whilst being able to navigate between them (using react-navigation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-webview

I have react-navigation set up in a react-native app like so.

```
 const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="ScanScreen" component={ScanScreen} options={{ title: 'Add a new app'}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="AppScreen" component={AppScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

In the AppScreen I am displaying webpages from external sources using react-native-webview like so.

```
const AppScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {

  const [uri, setUri] = useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params?.uri) {
      setUri(route.params?.uri);
    }
  }, [route.params?.app]);

  return (
  <View>
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: uri }}
      allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
      scrollEnabled={false}
    />
  </View>
  );
};
```

The HomeScreen just shows a list of apps the user can view in the AppScreen.
Whenever the user navigates between these two screens however, the webview in the AppScreen gets unmounted which means the state of the application and any granted permissions to it are lost, is there a way to stop this from happening?

Additionally, is there a way to use React Navigation (or any other form of navigation) to be able to have multiple instances of the AppScreen open at once, without them being unmounted? The functionality I'd like is similar to that of tabs in a browser, but since I'm rather new with React Native I'm unsure of what would be the right way to implement this.

Comment: You shoule create an tab component in AppScreen, and each tab contain WebView

Comment: Ok, I will try this approach.

Comment: @Alen.Toma It seems not to be possible to add new a new Tab.Screen during runtime, although it does keep the state per requested it doesn't fix my issue :(

Comment: Im not refereing to Stack.Navigator Im refering to creating a new custom component that can look like tabs

Comment: @RafeSiriso were you able to figure this out ? we need the same thing too.

Answer (score 0):

Edit; (2023) for react-navigation use it's bottom tabs library. It will keep those tabs mounted in memory once it loads. Switching tabs will not unmount the other opened WebViews.

Your WebViews must each be a tab (and you'll probably want to hide the tabs or customize the tab bar component) .

You can dynamically generate them using a state container when you want to make a new WebView.

Alternatives:
Consider using [react-native-navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/bottomTabs). The BottomTabs fit this use case perfectly.

Wix's library lets react-native open instances of itself on separate threads. This makes packages like Webview not interfere with each other across the instances.